# Iterate and print elements for 2d arrays in Jinja syntax

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, multidimensional-array, jinja2

I want to iterate a 2d array to print every element in one cell each, how can I write this in jinja?

My code so far only prints each row (containing three elements) in a single cell:

```
Data: [[90,50,30],
       [40,20,70],
       [60,80,10]]

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Value of Row 1</th>
          <th>Value of Row 2</th>
          <th>Value of Row 3</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for i in array %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
          <td>{{ i }}</td>
          <td>{{ i }}</td>
          <td>{{ i }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Expected output:

| No | Value of Row 1 | Value of Row 2 | Value of Row 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 50 | 30 |
| 2 | 40 | 20 | 70 |
| 3 | 60 | 80 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template to:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Value of Row 1</th>
          <th>Value of Row 2</th>
          <th>Value of Row 3</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
        {% for cell in row %}
          <td>{{ cell }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Note, you may also want to use loop to construct the table header.